# Foreach is only returning the first value

Tags: swift, foreach, swiftui

I am trying to output all elements to a list but the foreach loop only outputs the first and as many times as there are elements

If I try to display any element as follows `session.books[5].name` then I get the desired one and not the first

```
//...
List {
  ForEach(self.session.books) { book in
      Text(book.name)
  }
}
//...

//Model:
struct Book: Identifiable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
}

//This way I fetch books:
func getBooks() {
        db.collection("books").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
          guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
            print("No documents")
            return
          }

          self.books = documents.map { queryDocumentSnapshot -> Book in
            let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
            let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""

            return Book(id: .init(), name: name)
          }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
List {
  ForEach(self.session.books.indices, id: \.self) { index in
      Text(self.session.books[index].name)
  }
}
```

but it looks like something wrong with uniqueness of `id` for your books.

Comment: I updated the question, maybe now it becomes clear what is wrong with `id`?

Comment: It is clear now. All of your IDs are just empty strings.

Comment: @Jessy it is, thanks. in the model replaced `var id: String = UUID().uuidString` with `var id: UUID`

Comment: Why would a UUID ever be variable?